# WDS deploying Different architectures (64-bit and 32-bit) with a single boot image

Tags: dhcp, deployment, pxe-boot, wds

At the moment I have a WDS server set up with 2 Windows 7 boot images (32 Bit and 64 Bit) because we are running a mixed environment which will stay mixed for the near future.

We are moving to a VLAN network and my WDS server will will lose its DHCP distribution.

I am in the middle of planning the changes to have DHCP options configured on our switches but have come across a slight problem.

**THE PROBLEM:**

You can manually point to only one boot image though the manual DHcP option. I have done some research and according to a huge amount of responses online it seems that (theoretically) a **64-bit Boot Image** should be able to load both **x64 and x86 Install Images**

In practice it doesn't seem to be so straight forward because at the moment our x64 bit Boot Image only lists x64 bit install images and I am worried that when I do the change we will be limited.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this to verify, and a 32 bit boot image will display both 32 bit and 64 bit install images, while a 64 bit boot image will only display 64 bit install images. I also found [this TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ec32faf5-6488-4dcc-a3e6-dce284f200c7/wds-when-to-use-different-install-and-boot-images) which confirms my test results.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the silly question. In this case it was me not noticing the 1 64-Bit Image that pops up in the middle of about 20 x86 images. Thank you